# Macro to Remove Spacing Between Graphics/Text in Word 2010 Document?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, microsoft-word-2010

I frequently create Word (version 2010) documents that have only graphical items, and occasionally with some text beside a graphic, such as "New!" (that I would like to keep).  I would like to create a macro that would remove all spacing (of any type) from between all of these graphical/graphical with some text following items in the document- so that they all line up, one after the other until they fill up a line and then the next graphic would automatically begin on the next line (and then again repeat one graphic after another, without any spacing), etc.  Currently I am doing this by hand using arrow(s), delete and backspace keys, and it is very time consuming.  I have uploaded GIF images of "before/after" as to how the document would look before running the macro, and then after:

[image: Before Macro (Screenshot)][image: After Macro (Screenshot)]

As a side question, if I ever were to want to add just a certain number of spaces between the graphics, is there a way the maco could be "tweaked" to make this possible, easily?  If so, what text would I have to add to the macro to accomplish this, as well?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The built in Word "find and replace" tool can do 90% of the work for you. It can search on page breaks, paragraph marks, spaces and so on if you use the "More >>" option where a "Special" drop down button lives.

That "Special" button will allow you to select paragraphs, various different whitespace characters, line breaks and so on.

The other 10% can be done using the macro recorder on the VBA developer tab.

Start it recording, go through replacing all the line breaks, paragraph marks and so on until all you have is the images you want.

Then stop recording. Voila. Macro magic.

A quick test gives me the following to wipe out most of the various formatting types. `^p` corresponding to a "paragraph mark" and the find and replace tool is replacing it with `""` I.e. nothing.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^t"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^b"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^m"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

If you want a space between each image then simply change the `.Replacement.Text = ""` for each part to include a space like `.Replacement.Text = " "`

Comment: Brilliant! This worked perfectly and did exactly what I wanted. :-) Many thanks!!!!